# Run python server script via php file and display output

Tags: php, python

After many trials and many days of search I am asking this question. I have tried many online solutions but doesn't seem to work for me. I have a python file Server.py that starts the flask server for me.

[image]

I want to start this file from a php file and display output. Right now I am trying with exec() function but the webpage keeps running and I could not figure if the server has started or not.

I have tried following ways with exec() and making a batch file

```
exec('C:/foldername/py/apps/webapp/s.bat &');
or
exec('C:/foldername/py/apps/webapp/s.bat > /dev/null');
```

or

```
$command = "python C:/folder/server.py";
$pid = popen( $command,"r");
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I want in the end. I created a task schedule to open the batch file that can start my server. Then I set trigger on windows event. After that I created a batch file which creates an event in windows event logger and a php script to run that batch file. So, finally I was able to start python server file by php script with the help of task scheduler.